Trying to Install Ubuntu. Says 'boot file not found' but then loads into Ubuntu startup
I am a newbie when it comes to Linux and want to install it alongside Windows 11.
I have downloaded Ubuntu 24.04 onto my flashdrive, when I insert it into my computer (Lenovo Thinkpad Carbon x1 gen 11) I get the message 'error boot file not found' but then a few seconds later it loads into the screen that lets me choose to install Ubuntu.
For now, I have just tested Ubuntu and not actually installed it. I have tried a few other flashdrives (varying brands) to see if it was an issue with the brand or not. Those have all yielded the same screen ('error file not found') but then loads into Ubuntu a few moments later.
I am wondering if this is actually an issue or not? If it is, what do I need to do to fix it? Like I said, I am a newbie at Linux so I apologize for any ignorance.

You don't need to worry about this.  I recently did some installs and saw this too, but everything works.  I suspect a program (shimx64.efi) was checking for a file (grub.cfg) which used to be required to be in the same directory, but recent ISOs do not have it there. The program was changed a bit to look in other places, and eventually finds it, but the error message was still produced.  To check on this supposition, you can look at the shim source, it's not large, but I haven't bothered since things are working.
